# xlwings 0.6.1 Import error on Mac OS X with python 3.5

Tags: macos, python-3.5, xlwings

When importing xlwings 0.6.1 in Python 3.5 on a Mac, I'm getting the following error message:

Python 3.5.0 (default, Nov  8 2015, 20:38:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import xlwings
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlwings/**init**.py", line 22, in 
> > >           from . import _xlmac as xlplatform
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xlwings/_xlmac.py", line 5, in 
> > >           from appscript import app, mactypes
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aeosa/appscript/**init**.py", line 8, in 
> > >           from aem.findapp import ApplicationNotFoundError
> > >         File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aeosa/aem/**init**.py", line 5, in 
> > >           import ae, kae, findapp, mactypes, aemconnect
> > >       ImportError: No module named 'ae'

Has anyone encountered this error with the recent release of xlwings 0.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to have gone wrong with the installation of the `appscript` package, a dependency of xlwings. Try to reinstall that. But generally speaking, I would suggest to open an issue on GitHub for these kind of questions since there is usually something very specific going on. For ease of installation, I recommend to use the Anaconda distribution.