# ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_osx' from partially initialized module 'psutil

Tags: python, macos

Error occur when execute the python script file.

python version is 2.7.10

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zl96/Sites/mobileSMSPythonv2/mobileSMS/mobileSMSlocal.py", line 17, in <module>
    import psutil   #to get process memory usage
  File "/Users/zl96/Sites/mobileSMSPythonv2/mobileSMS/psutil/__init__.py", line 151, in <module>
    from . import _psosx as _psplatform
  File "/Users/zl96/Sites/mobileSMSPythonv2/mobileSMS/psutil/_psosx.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import _psutil_osx as cext
ImportError: cannot import name '_psutil_osx' from partially initialized module 'psutil' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Have you installed psutil library?

Comment: i think got. pip3 list there show psutil 5.6.5

Comment: Can you share how you import libraries in the code?

Comment: I import like this ==> elif MACOS:    from . import _psosx as _psplatform

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem: I deleted any folders with the name `psutil` from my site-packages.

```
pip install psutil
```

I then got the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aem.ae'
```

On the advice of this website:
[xlwings 0.6.1 Import error on Mac OS X with python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119693/xlwings-0-6-1-import-error-on-mac-os-x-with-python-3-5)

I then entered:

```
pip uninstall appscript
pip install appscript
```

That solved it.